# ScrollSpy - Offset attribute does not work in javascript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scrollspy

I'm testing out Bootstrap-ScrollSpy. And I made it work. I wanted to use the offeset attribute in a JavaScript File in Ruby on Rails. Unfortunately I can't make it work. I'm using rails 4. I have a welcomes controller and an index action/view.

**How can I make this work?**

If you need any further information just let me know.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Scrolltest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<div id="navbar-example">
  <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="header">
    <%= image_tag("header.jpg", alt: "header", :class => "header") %>
</div>
<div id="about">
    <h2>About</h2> 
</div>
<div id="services">
    <h2>Services</h2> 
</div>
<div id="portfolio">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2> 
</div>
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2> 
</div>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'scrollspy-rails'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require_tree .
```

**welcomes.js**

```
(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  ("body").scrollspy({target: "#navbar-example", offset: 100});
});
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you find it important to also include the Scrollspy plugin in your application?

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu the documentation of the bootstrap-sass gem states that If I am using Sprockets or Mincer, you can require bootstrap-sprockets instead to load the individual modules. //= require bootstrap-sprockets in application.js loads all the modules for me. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Scrollspy is not part of bootstrap 3, it's a plugin for it.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu I have added the gem 'scrollspy-rails' and run bundle install I have also added //= require bootstrap/scrollspy in application.js but it still does not work? Any hints?

Comment: There's no such thing as 'doesn't work'. Surely you're getting an error or something.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu I have checked the Console in Developer Tools in Chrome. I dont get any Error Message. I have also added <p class="replace_by_js">No Javascript</p> in index.html.erb and $('p.replace_by_js').replaceWith("<p>Javascript Enabled!</p>") in the js function. I get still "No Javascript"!